# How to validate ZK Textbox by using HTML5+CSS3 validation?

Tags: html, css, jquery-validate, zk

I'm using ZK7, HTML5, CSS3 and I'm trying to validate below zk textbox element if it is a valid email:

```
<form id="validation-form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="block clearfix" for="email">
                <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                    <z:textbox id="emailInput" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="${labels.login.email}"/>
                    <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <button id="forgotPassword" type="button" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                <i class="icon-lightbulb"></i>
                ${labels.send}
            </button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {

        $('[data-rel=tooltip]').tooltip();

        $(".select2").css('width','200px').select2({allowClear:true})
        .on('change', function(){
            $(this).closest('form').validate().element($(this));
        }); 


        var $validation = false;

        //documentation : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

        $('#validation-form').validate({

            errorElement: 'div',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            focusInvalid: false,
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email:true
                }
            },

            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: "Please provide a valid email.",
                    email: "Please provide a valid email."
                }
            },

            invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
                $('.alert-danger', $('.login-form')).show();
            },

            highlight: function (e) {
                $(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-info').addClass('has-error');
            },

            success: function (e) {
                $(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-info');
                $(e).remove();
            },

            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if(element.is(':checkbox') || element.is(':radio')) {
                    var controls = element.closest('div[class*="col-"]');
                    if(controls.find(':checkbox,:radio').length > 1) controls.append(error);
                    else error.insertAfter(element.nextAll('.lbl:eq(0)').eq(0));
                }
                else if(element.is('.select2')) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.siblings('[class*="select2-container"]:eq(0)'));
                }
                else if(element.is('.chosen-select')) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.siblings('[class*="chosen-container"]:eq(0)'));
                }
                else error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {
            },
            invalidHandler: function (form) {
            }
        });




        $('#modal-wizard .modal-header').ace_wizard();
        $('#modal-wizard .wizard-actions .btn[data-dismiss=modal]').removeAttr('disabled');
    })
</script>
```

It is working when I change z:textbox to html input as:

```
<input id="emailInput" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="${labels.login.email}"/>
```

How should I do the same by using zk textbox?

Comment: You can replace this entire line: `$(this).closest('form').validate().element($(this))` with only this:  `$(this).valid()`

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear, because if you're using the jQuery Validate plugin, then you're not using HTML 5 validation.  (_The plugin dynamically **disables** HTML 5 validation_).  Also, show us the ***rendered*** HTML markup as seen in the browser, **not** the code you've uploaded to your server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you wanted, cause your question has a lot of javascript, jquery and the first code doesn't really looks like zk(only your internationalization is familiar).
If you use zk you can do the following :

```
<textbox value="@bind(vm.email)" id="email" 
   constraint="/.+@(.+\.[a-z]+|)/: Please enter a valid e-mail address" 
   type="email" placeholder="enter email" />
```

I did put a simpel email constraint there, but you can change the constraint to what you want.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There is this nice [example](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/effects/form_effect) of integrating jquery masks with zk.
For client side validation this should be fine.
In addition, ZK offers [form validation](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/DataBinding/Validator) as well as [constraints for `InputElement`s](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Base_Components/InputElement)